# Conditional :enter Animation of Component in Angular

Tags: angular, router, angular-animations

Given my app routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    {path: 'datascreen', component: DataComponent},
    {path: '', component: IntroComponent}
  ]
  }
];
```

I do have a Homescreen which should show the IntroComponent by default. When the user clicks on a button on that Intro-component, it navigates to the DataComponent.

With a button on the DataComponent the user can navigate back to the Intro-Component.

The template of the HomeComponent does only contain the outlet:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I do want to add a slide-in/slide-out animation to the IntroComponent. This can easily be done by adding an animation to the IntroComponent with a trigger on ":enter" and ":leave". This works fine.

But exactly this animation is now also shown when the screen is rendered for the first time. And this looks somehow confusing.

**So my question is:**
How can I add an animation to the IntroComponent which is only executed after the initial load? Or in other words: How can the :enter animation be executed on the second appearance of the component?

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz example, so it would be easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating angular animations you have a few states that are important.  The first state is `void => *`. This is the same as the shorthand `:enter`

When you first load a view you are hitting that Animation Event.
If you put a trigger inside the component then EVERYTIME you start that component its going to fire off that trigger, just like every time you run a component its going to fire off the code inside ngOnInit. So the solution to your problem is to move the animation OUT of the component and instead WRAP your router outlet with an animation trigger that controls the animation of the entire application.

You want to set your `:enter` to be whatever the animation of your application loading is, like a fade in or something relevant, then you would want to set your animations from route 1 to route 2 using your slide in and slide out methods.  This way if you navigate it slides left and right, but if you LOAD it just fades in.

Taken from YearofMoo
[Year of Moo Routable Animations](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html#routable-animations)

**app.html**

```
<div [@routeAnimation]="prepRouteState(routerOutlet)">
  <!-- make sure to keep the ="outlet" part -->
  <router-outlet #routerOutlet="outlet"></div>
<div>
```

Then

**app.ts**

```
@Component({
animations: [
trigger('routeAnimation', [
  // no need to animate anything on load
  transition(':enter', []),
  // when we go away from the home page to support
  transition('homePage => supportPage', [
      group([
        query(':enter', [
          style({ opacity: 0 }),
          animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        query(':leave', [
          animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ])
      ])
    ]),
  // and when we go back home
  transition('supportPage => homePage', [
    // ...
  ])
])
]
})
class AppComponent {
  prepRouteState(outlet: any) {
  return outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'] || 'firstPage'; 
}
}
```

**app.ts**

```
const ROUTES = [
  { path: '',
    component: HomePageComponent,
    data: {
      animation: 'homePage'
    }
  },
  { path: 'support',
    component: SupportPageComponent,
    data: {
      animation: 'supportPage'
    }
  }    
]
```

Comment: Long but good answer. The transition(':enter', []) part is crucial here, else is optional. You can have a wild card transition('* => *) with enter/leave states instead.of defining all transitions manually